# Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'MYDOMAIN.COM' while getting initial credentials

Tags: docker, azure, kerberos

I'm using AzureDevOps and have project with DockerCompose file. While building it locally within working network it looks good. But when I run build (Docker Compose task with Build services action) in AzurePipelines it crashed with error -  Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'MYDOMAIN.COM' while getting initial credentials. I assumed that Ubuntu Agent is not configured to work properly with Kerberos. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are your KDCs actually accessible from the outside? Does the realm have SRV records pointing to KDCs?

Comment: I find workaround of that issue. I setup self-hosted agent and run build on it successfully. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install